Tripotent rings has characteristics 6
Tripotent ring : A ring $R$ is said to be tripotent ring if for each $a\in R$, it implies that $a^3=a$.
Like Boolean rings have characteristics 2, can we prove that tripotent rings have characteristics 6. Let us try to prove. Suppose $(a+a)^3=a+a$
$8a^3=2a$
$8a=2a$
$6a=0$.
Is this correct?

$6a=0$ doesn't mean that $6$ is the characteristic. It only means the characteristic divides $6$. For example, note that $\mathbb{F_2}$ and $\mathbb{F_3}$ are tripotent.

Yes, I didn't notice it. Thanks. So what can be the characteristics of tripotent rings.

The divisors of 6: 2 or 3 or 6.

Such a ring is necessarily commutative. This is an exercise in Herstein's algebra book, the second edition was 1975, the exercise is page 136, number 19.
